# Can't connect to MySQL database using MySQLConnection

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm using the MySqlConnection class to connect to a local MySQL database:

```
SourceHost = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sourceHost"];
SourceDatabase = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sourceDatabase"];
SourceUsername = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sourceUsername"];
SourcePassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sourcePassword"];

SourceString = String.Format("Server={0};Database={1};UID={2};Password={3};", SourceHost, SourceDatabase, SourceUsername, SourcePassword);
var sqlSourceConnection = new MySqlConnection(SourceString);

sqlSourceConnection.Open();
```

These are the values in the App.config file

```
<add key="sourceHost" value="myHost" />
<add key="sourceDatabase" value="myDB" />
<add key="sourceUsername" value="myUSer" />
<add key="sourcePassword" value="myPSW" />
<add key="sourceDbType" value="mysql" />
```

The error I get is saying: Access denied for user myUser@myHost.myDomain using password:YES, but by using the myUser and myPSW credentials I can login from the command prompt.

What's wrong?

EDIT: It worked when I changed the sourceHost to

```
<add key="sourceHost" value="localhost" />
```

Comment: Are you running the code on and from the same host you're trying on the command line?

Comment: Check the port. MySQL usually defines the port as being 3306, but if you've changed it, or is using another distribution (say, MariaDB), the credentials will crash.
Other solution: Check if your user has the permission to read your database.

Comment: @mable yes, I am running it from the command line

Comment: I checked the database and it is using the port 3306. The user I am trying to login is root.

Comment: It started working when I replaced the machine name with localhost. I think it was trying to use some form of domain authentication instead of the SQL login.

Comment: This does not solve your problem. But why don't you store complete connection string as single row in `connectionstrings` section?

Comment: If you ever want to take a different approach, Microsoft has a library called [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) which IMHO is a lot easier to use for manipulating and querying databases. EDIT: Added link for EF

Comment: Entity Framework is great, but it can throw some huge annoyances at you with mysql. Mysql by default forces lowercase table names.  EF generates SQL for Camel Case tables unless you manually tell it to use a lowercase table name.  Also using code first migrations it generates sql with dbo.tablename, and the dbo. part is invalid, so you always have to go and delete dbo. w/e you see it.

Those 2 gotchas took me days to debug...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User myUser is only authorized from localhost. 
You need to authorize myUser for your hostname.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* to 'myUser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

or

```
GRANT ON *.* TO 'myUser'@'myHost.myDomain' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' ;
```

or you can also do

```
GRANT ON *.* TO 'myUser'@'%.myDomain' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Standard**

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

**Specifying TCP port**

```
Server=myServerAddress;Port=1234;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

The port 3306 is the default MySql port.The value is ignored if Unix socket is used.

Answer (score 0):

When you try [`SHOW GRANTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-grants.html) you should see line like this:

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS;
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'myUSer'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Note the `localhost`, so this happens with the connection:

- When you try to connect to `localhost` system automatically uses `127.0.0.1` as connection source address.
- But when you connect to `10.0.0.1` it uses `10.0.0.1` as your source address.

Just try [ping with `-S`](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/commandlinereference/p/ping-command.htm):

```
C:\>ping localhost -S 127.0.0.1

Pinging localhost [127.0.0.1] from 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

C:\>ping localhost -S 10.0.0.1

Pinging localhost [127.0.0.1] from 10.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
PING: transmit failed. General failure.

C:\>ping 10.0.0.1 -S 10.0.0.1

Pinging 10.0.0.1 from 10.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

C:\>ping 10.0.0.1 -S 127.0.0.1

Pinging 10.0.0.1 from 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
```

So it works with `localhost`, because `localhost` is an *allowed source host*, and it doesn't with `your_host` because `10.0.0.1` is not an allowed host.

Just grant privileges for your user to `10.0.0.1` and it should work (maybe you'll have to change firewall settings), or allow all connection from the outside (using `%` as host).